# New PayPal Android SDK - testing with Sandbox accounts set to US in testing environment

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm writing an educational paper about the recent PayPal Android mobile SDK ([link)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/android-integration-guide/) and will have to implement an app with it.

While this is available only in the US for now, I've seen that you can set the country of the merchant and personal accounts in the Sandbox for test accounts.

Is it possible to try out the new Android SDK and implement an Android app with only a test account set to US for that cause (my physical location is outside US)? I'm not planning to use the app in live environment, only for testing purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended option is to set the environment to `ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK` which is a fully mocked development mode that will not perform any network operations whatsoever. That should give you a chance to see the UI, card.io scanner, etc. but without any server dependencies.

As an FYI, the SDK does not check your location via GPS or device sensors. As long as the `client_id` and `PayPalPayment` objects are valid, the SDK should work.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm a non-U.S. developer. How does the site redesign affect me?**
You can use our Classic APIs (like Checkout and PayPal Payments Standard) for new integrations. If you don't have a PayPal account, you can create a new Business account for your country.

If you've previously used our Classic APIs, you can continue to use them. You can import existing Sandbox accounts on the Sandbox Accounts page by using you old Sandbox email address and password.

Our REST APIs and the PayPal Mobile SDK are currently targeted only for the U.S. market. However, we'll be rolling them out to other countries over the rest of the year.

Ref: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support/faq

Comment: Thank you I've read this, but that still doesn't answer my specific question about using the SDK just for testing. I do have an existing registered account and have created merchant and personal sandbox testing accounts set to US. I'm positive that the statement "Our REST APIs and the PayPal Mobile SDK are currently targeted only for the U.S. market." are meant for live usage - or I'm wrong. That's what I'm asking.